# Why isn't /usr/local/bin/ checked in check_flexlm.pl ? Source included

Tags: linux, perl, nagios, nrpe

Eventhough I have `/usr/local/bin/lmstat` the below script always fails with `Cannot find "lmstat"`.

Can anyone see why that is the case?

```
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
use vars qw($opt_V $opt_h $opt_F $opt_t $verbose $PROGNAME);
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin";
use lib '/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins';
use utils qw(%ERRORS &print_revision &support &usage);

$PROGNAME="check_flexlm";

sub print_help ();
sub print_usage ();

$ENV{'PATH'}='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin';
$ENV{'BASH_ENV'}='';
$ENV{'ENV'}='';

Getopt::Long::Configure('bundling');
GetOptions
        ("V"   => \$opt_V,   "version"    => \$opt_V,
         "h"   => \$opt_h,   "help"       => \$opt_h,
         "v"   => \$verbose, "verbose"    => \$verbose,
         "F=s" => \$opt_F,   "filename=s" => \$opt_F,
         "t=i" => \$opt_t, "timeout=i"  => \$opt_t);

if ($opt_V) {
        print_revision($PROGNAME,'2.2.1');
        exit $ERRORS{'OK'};
}

unless (defined $opt_t) {
        $opt_t = $utils::TIMEOUT ;      # default timeout
}


if ($opt_h) {print_help(); exit $ERRORS{'OK'};}

unless (defined $opt_F) {
        $opt_F = $ENV{'LM_LICENSE_FILE'};
        unless (defined $opt_F) {
                print "Missing license.dat file\n";
                print_usage();
                exit $ERRORS{'UNKNOWN'};
        }
}
# Just in case of problems, let's not hang Nagios
$SIG{'ALRM'} = sub {
        print "Timeout: No Answer from Client\n";
        exit $ERRORS{'UNKNOWN'};
};
alarm($opt_t);

my $lmstat = $utils::PATH_TO_LMSTAT ;
unless (-x $lmstat ) {
        print "Cannot find \"lmstat\"\n";
        exit $ERRORS{'UNKNOWN'};
}
```

Comment: is `utils` your own module? Because without knowing what `$utils::PATH_TO_LMSTAT` says we cannot help.

Comment: `-x "lmstat"` will not search your PATH. It will just check the file `lmstat` in the current directory. To test for an executable named `lmstat` in your PATH, run `which lmstat` and check the exit code.

Comment: @mob No it is the unmodified code. I have no idea what that part does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never assume you know what something is. Try printing the path to verify it is what you think it is:

```
unless (-x $utils::PATH_TO_LMSTAT ) {
    print qq/Cannot find "lmstat" at <$utils::PATH_TO_LMSTAT>\n/;
    exit $ERRORS{'UNKNOWN'};
}
```

If `$utils::PATH_TO_LMSTAT` is a relative path (such as `lmstat` by itself) the `-x` is looking in the current directory. If it's a full path, maybe you have the string wrong.

Note that your options handling can be a bit less unwieldy since you can specify multiple names for options in the same key:

```
GetOptions(
        "V|version"    => \$opt_V,
        "h|help"       => \$opt_h,
        "v|verbose"    => \$verbose,
        "F|filename=s" => \$opt_F,
        "t|timeout=i"  => \$opt_t,
        );
```

The "Secure Programming Techniques" chapter of [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org) discusses many of the headaches of programs that call external programs.